# Increase the speed of pulling data from a Rest Api in R

Tags: r, get, httr, get-request

I am pulling data from an API using R and I was wondering if I could speed up the call. Usually after pulling the data I have to use a few other functions to get the desired output. This usually slows down my code quite a bit.

Here is a reproducible example: (api key works as its a free one)

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
data = GET("https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=AAPL&resolution=1&from=1572651390&to=1572910590&token=btj392748v6p9f1po5vg")
value = data$content
value = rawToChar(value)
value = fromJSON(value)

head(value$c, 10)
#[1] 257.57 257.07 257.14 257.37 257.57 257.66
```

Is there a way to speed up my call from the server? I find that I have to do this with many api's i hook up to. Speed is important to me. If any of you could suggest a better method that would be greatly appreciated.

@dave2e had a great idea that worked - just call fromJson("url goes here").

However, some api's i call from require a header. This is how I usually call it with GET().

```
token = "mysecretpassword"
value = GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = token))
```

How can i do this in fromJson()?

Comment: Try accessing the URL directly `jsonlite::fromJSON("**URL goes here**")` will return a list of values.  Not much can be done to improve the time to request and receive a web request.

Comment: thanks @Dave2e I have edited my post. Could you please opine. Once solved post answer and i will give it a check mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't control the download or remote server.  But you control the JSON conversion, and nothing is faster than [simdjson](https://simdjson.org) which you can use via [RcppSimdJson](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=RcppSimdJson).

#### Code

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(RcppSimdJson)
library(rbenchmark)
data <- GET("https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=AAPL&resolution=1&from=1572651390&to=1572910590&token=btj392748v6p9f1po5vg")
benchmark(value1 <- fromJSON(rawToChar(data$content)),
          value2 <- RcppSimdJson::fparse(data$content), 
          replications=1000[,1:4]
```

#### Output

```
R> library(httr)
R> library(jsonlite)
R> library(RcppSimdJson)
R> library(rbenchmark)
R> data <- GET("https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=AAPL&resolution=1&from=1572651390&to=1572910590&token=btj392748v6p9f1po5vg")
R> benchmark(value1 <- fromJSON(rawToChar(data$content)),
+           value2 <- RcppSimdJson::fparse(data$content), replications=1000)[,1:4]
                                          test replications elapsed relative
1  value1 <- fromJSON(rawToChar(data$content))         1000   0.987   13.708
2 value2 <- RcppSimdJson::fparse(data$content)         1000   0.072    1.000
R>
```

So that conversion aspect is now 13 times faster. Whether that matters in your overall context is something only you can decide.

Comment: On rstudio cloud i get this error when installing the package. "Error: C++17 standard requested but CXX17 is not defined"

Comment: That can happen. We request / require a C++17 compiler, that R version and its `g++` may be too old.  If you know this stuff you can probably relax it in the package sources, and we may do so in a future release and this requirement was relaxed in the upstream `simdjson` code.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I'm pushing base64 converted image content via POST API call to a remote server. It takes almost 15-20 minutes for each images. The images are fairly larger 1400 x10,000 . Wondering if you know any  better way to speed up the POST api call